# Trying to prove a seemingly easy fact on ideals of ternary C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, ideals

Currently I'm reading the paper by Abadie and Ferraro titled [Applications of ternary rings to $C^*$-algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08476).

Recall that a $C^{\ast}$-ternary ring is a complex Banach space $M$, equipped with a ternary product $(x,y,z) \to [x,y,z]$ of $M^3$ into $M$ which is linear in the outer variables, conjugate linear in the middle variable, associative in the sense that   $[[x,y,z],u,v]=[x,y,[z,u,v]]= [x,[u,z,y],v]$ and also satisfies $\lVert[x,x,x]\rVert= \lVert x \rVert ^3$ and $\lVert[x,y,z]\rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert\lVert y \rVert\lVert z \rVert$. According to definition 4.1 of the same paper, a subspace $I$ of $M$ is called an ideal of $M$ provided $[I,M,M]+[M,M,I] \subset I$. After the definition of ideal the following fact is given without proof:

> Let $I$ be a closed ideal of $M$ then $[M,I, M] \subset I$.

I don't see an immediate proof of this fact. Can someone give the proof?

Comment: TeX note: norms should be typeset as $\lVert x\rVert$ `\lVert x\rVert`, not $\vert\vert x\vert\vert$ `\vert\vert x\vert\vert`.  Note especially the improved spacing when two norms are multiplied:  $\lVert x\rVert\lVert y\rVert$ `\lVert x\rVert\lVert y\rVert` *versus* $\vert\vert x\vert\vert\vert\vert y\vert\vert$ `\vert\vert x\vert\vert\vert\vert y\vert\vert`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: There's some extra module structure needed to get to a C*-ternary ring. What you are describing is *-ternary ring. I'm not super clear on the specifics but the extra conditions will yield this result.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey: I don't see anything missed here in the definition of $C^*$-ternary ring. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: At the start of section 4 they say that $M$ is an $M^l - M^r$ bimodule satisfying $\langle x,y\rangle_l z = [x,y,z] = x\langle y,z\rangle_r$. I am guessing that this is what will be needed to prove the result.